# How can I add title in excel report in Laravel?

Tags: excel, laravel, download

This is my controller Code?

```
$items = Excel::create('Gin_Report', function($excel) use ($ginItems) {
            $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use ($ginItems) {
                $sheet->fromArray($ginItems);
            });

        })->export('csv');
```

Is it possible to pass title through this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which library you are using, but if based on PHPSpreadsheet or PHPExcel, you can use the **worksheet** object to set the page title:

```
 $sheet->setTitle('My Page');
```

From the actual spreadsheet object, you can do this through get properties along with a few other things:

```
$ea = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet(); // ea is short for Excel Application
$ea->getProperties()
        ->setCreator('Me')
        ->setTitle('Building Listing')
        ->setLastModifiedBy('Me');
```

If you are talking about the name of the file, that can be done as you write the sheet:

```
$this->writeSheet($ea, 'My File Name');
```

Comment: I'm using [https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/getting-started/] LaravelExcel

Comment: That's built on PHPExcel, so the above should work along with all native PHPExcel functions.  Did you try the first item (`$sheet->setTitle()`) within the inner closure?

Comment: If you added it within the closure it should work.  An alternative to try is:  `$excel->sheet('MY TITLE HERE', function($sheet) use ($ginItems) {...}`.  This may feed the same method as above.

Comment: `$sheet->setTitle()` Is this added as a title of the table or title of the sheet?

Comment: Title of the sheet.  Title of the table is just a row within your data, styled as you wish.